# Converting two columns to rows to correspond with user_id from a time-series dataset

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series dataset I need to modify and I'd like to convert two columns to rows with corresponding values for each user_id. Here is an image of the time series dataset called AllData.

[AllData time series dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz8qx.png)

As you can see each user_id has 25 values for Week and Average.Steps. I was able to condense the dataset by user_id with the following code to create a new data set called Users. I've provided an image of the output following the code:

```
Users <- AllData %>%
 select(user_id,gender,age,income_level,Province,current_provider,Baseline,Experience,Engagement_pre, first_baseline)%>%
 distinct(user_id, gender,age,income_level,Province,current_provider,Baseline,Experience,Engagement_pre, first_baseline)%>%
 mutate(female = if_else(gender == 'Female', 1, 0))
```

[Users dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJHZI.png)

Here each user_id is in a distinct row with values for the corresponding columns I selected. I would like to include Week and Average.Steps from AllData but I don't know how to incorporate additional code into the one I made for Users so each value of Week and Average.Steps corresponds with user_id. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It would be helpful if you made a minimal working example instead of providing photos. Additionally, you removed these variables when you didn't include them in the select statement. So if I were you I would just include them in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the average from AllData or from `distinct` rows? There isn't enough data in the image to understand how or what is replicated.

This is the average by user and week.

```
library(tidyverse)

# find the averages
summaryAD <- AllData %>% 
     group_by(user_id, Week) %>% 
     summarise(steps = mean(Average.Steps))

finalData <- left_join(Users, summaryAD) # join the averages with your data
```

Comment: The Average.Steps for distinct rows. Right now each user_id has 25 values for each week of the study in AllData. In Users, I want each user_id row to have values from Week and Average.Steps columns in the AllData data frame for an additional 25 rows for Week (1:25) with corresponding Average.Steps. Sorry for the confusion regarding the images, I'm working with a very large dataset

Comment: If I understand you correctly then that's what is coded above. That being said, I'm missing something! The code above will provide one value per user per week. So if there are 10 weeks per user, you'll have 10 averages, one per user, per week. If there are 25 values per week currently then it's the average steps is the average of those 25 observations.